# Documenting Object with methods and their return values in JSDoc

Tags: jsdoc

I have a paging controller factory, that returns a paging controller Object with a bunch of methods (for the view to interact with, especially when an end-user does an action like navigate to a different page or enter some search text). It is defined something like:

```
/**
 * Returns a paging controller object with data
 * @param {Object[]} data 
 * @param {string} prop the property containing that data. If it's a function, it should be no-args.
 * @param {filterFunc} filterer a callback that filters the data
 */
function pagingControllerFor(data, prop, filterer) { 
    let _currentPage = 0
  let _filterFunc = filterer
  let _stateChange = false
  let _data;
  const _ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 50

  let _selectAllChecked = [];

  /**
   * Getter for all the data. Useful for debugging.
   */
  function getAllData() { 
    if (prop) { 
      if (typeof data[prop] === 'function') { 
        return data[prop]()
      }
      return data[prop]
    }
    return data
  }

  /**
   * Always returns fresh data for the controller
   */
  function getData() { 
    let data = getAllData()
    if (_filterFunc) { 
      if ((_stateChange) || (!_data)) {
        _data = data.filter(_filterFunc)
        _selectAllChecked = Array(Math.ceil(_data.length / _ITEMS_PER_PAGE)).fill(false)
        _stateChange = false
      }
      return _data
    }
    return data
  }

return {
  /* a whole bunch of methods irrelevant to my use case on here */
  getCurrentPageData   : () => getData().slice(_currentPage * _ITEMS_PER_PAGE, (_currentPage + 1) * _ITEMS_PER_PAGE),
  // get/set current "Select All" checkbox state
    isCurrentSelectAllChecked : () => _selectAllChecked[_currentPage],
    setCurrentSelectAllChecked : (checked) => _selectAllChecked[_currentPage] = checked
    }

}
```

I am writing an event-binder for the "Select/Deselect All" checkboxes on the view being paginated. It is, as of the time I wrote this, defined to be:

```
/**
 * Binds clicks on the current "Select/Deselect All" checkbox to the controller
 * @param {string} modalType 
 * @param {{ getCurrentPageData : () => Array<{IsSelectedOnModal : boolean}>, setCurrentSelectAllChecked : () => boolean }} controller 
 * @param {Function} callback 
 */
function bindToggleSelectAllEvent(modalType, controller, callback) { 
  callback = callback || bindToggleSelectAllEvent

  const modalSelector = `#${modalType}-selector-modal`


  $(`#toggle-all-${(modalType === ITEM) ? 'items' : 'categories'}-selected`)
    .off('change')
    .on('change', function() { 
      // get the state of this 
      let isChecked = $(this).prop('checked')
      // change the selection state of all current items/categories in the controller to that state
      controller.getCurrentPageData().forEach((data) => {
        data.IsSelectedOnModal = isChecked
      })
      // tell the controller the new state of this "Select All" checkbox
      controller.setCurrentSelectAllChecked(isChecked)
      // Re-render modal?!
      // TODO: implement this
    })
}
```

VSCode knows what I'm doing, as it detects the relevant methods of `controller`, which I have specified.
[image]

However, JSDoc doesn't, for some reason:

```
ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file [my-project-path]\static\js\menu\edit\index.js in line 433 with tag title "param" and text "{{ getCurrentPageData : () => Array<{IsSelectedOnModal : boolean}>, setCurrentSelectAllChecked : () => boolean }} controller": Invalid type expression "{ getCurrentPageData : () => Array<{IsSelectedOnModal : boolean}>, setCurrentSelectAllChecked : () => boolean }": Expected "," or "}" but "=" found.

ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file [my-project-path]\static\js\menu\edit\index.js in line 439 with tag title "param" and text "{{ getCurrentPageData : () => Array<{IsSelectedOnModal : boolean}>, setCurrentSelectAllChecked : () => boolean }} controller": Invalid type expression "{ getCurrentPageData : () => Array<{IsSelectedOnModal : boolean}>, setCurrentSelectAllChecked : () => boolean }": Expected "," or "}" but "=" found.
```

**What should I do about this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code support TypeScript types in JS Docs but the JS Doc tool only supports [Closure types](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#type-expressions).

I believe that the arrow function type expressions that you are using are valid TypeScript types but cannot be understood by the JSDoc tool. Try using the `function():` [function type syntax](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#function-type) instead

```
@param {{ getCurrentPageData : function(): Array<{IsSelectedOnModal : boolean}> }} controller
```